# https redirection - image logo loaded from unsecure source

Tags: magento-1.9, https

We've recently migrated the whole magento webshop to the http**s** structure.

There comes the issue: The product pages are still unsecure, because each product logo is loaded from an unsecure source. Here is the Google Inspector insight:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'product-page-url' was loaded
>   over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>   'http://www.safegear.dk/media/brand/birkegaarden.gif'. This content
>   should also be served over HTTPS.

The logo that is loaded over http is the one of "Birkegaarden", in the top right (see image)[image: product_page]

Thanks to everyone who will be taking a minute to read these few lines!

Enrico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select Current Configuration Scope and go to Advanced > Developer > Template Path Hints and turn this on to find where the template is that is controlling the brand logo.

then change the URL structure so it is similar to this:

```
<img src="{{media url='wysiwyg/brands/image.jpg' _secure="true" }}"
```

Or just add https or remove http:

Comment: That´s GREAT!Thank you so much @Mike Tim Turner !!I totally solved the problem! I would add that a store view should be selected before finding the "Template Path Hints" option...it is not showing in Default view.

Comment: Updated my answer :)